How to accept Android SDK license when github is blocked by firewall
Github.com is blocked by firewall. When I run following command in flutter to accept Android SDK license then it fails due to blocking. I am using Windows. Is there an alternate way of accepting license?
flutter doctor --android-licenses
EDIT
I ran following command and accepted all licenses but still flutter doctor is asking to accept license.
sdkmanager --licenses
